# Unable to Create C# Class from JSON

Tags: c#, json, class

We have to consume a new API in our web application and they are giving the below JSON response.

I used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for creating the C# classes; however, it gave invalid names for emails and phone numbers in it.

Is this a valid JSON ? If so, can you please help creating a C# class for this?

```
{
  "customer": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "abc@gmail.com": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "def@gmail.com": [
          "",
          ""
        ]
      },
      "custPhone": {
        "1234567890": [
          "",
          ""
        ]
      },
      "custIDString": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the need for an array under email address and phone number

"abc@gmail.com": [
                    "",                   
                    ""
                ]

Comment: Thank You Every one for your responses. @ Vivek Natarajan and all, each customer can have multiple emails and each email has its own properties like date when the email was added to customer database, date when it got updated, whether the email has been selected for receiving promotion emails etc like "abc@gmail.com": [ "05/01/2019", "05/08/2019" ,"Y"]  where email address is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is a json valid format, for the next time you are in doubt here is a webpage where you can check https://jsonlint.com/ .

And about your second question, while it is a valid json format... its not really a valid c# class. Because in the names of the variables you are having numbers. So did actually make this json?

Comment: Thanks @nalnpir, I have informed the API team that a valid c# class could not be created from their JSON and now they are providing a valid JSON response for which I could create valid c# classes.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the json is valid, but the values are interpreted as property-names. If you want something like this:

```
public class EmailAddresses
{
    public List<string> emailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class CustPhoneNumbers
{
    public List<string> custPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public EmailAddresses emailAddresses { get; set; }
    public CustPhoneNumbers custPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public string custIDString { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Customer> customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then your json has to look like this:

```
{
    "customer": [{

        "emailAddresses": {
            "emailAddress": [
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "def@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        "custPhoneNumbers": {
            "custPhoneNumber": [
                "123456789",
                "121212121"
            ]
        },
        "custIDString": ""
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This JSON is valid, but rather odd.  You will need to use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to handle the email addresses and phone numbers, since they are keys, not values, in the JSON.

Here is the class structure you need:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Customer> customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> emailAddress{ get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> custPhone{ get; set; }
    public string custIDString { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the JSON into the `RootObject` class.

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZhHKJf